# Modify a 3D Model of a Turnstile

Tags: export, collada

I'm completely new to Blender. I have a DAE file which has 4 access turnstiles and I want to delete one of them to create a 3 access turnstile. I'm using this in Sweet Home 3D.

I have imported the DAE file into Blender and have deleted one of the turnstiles. I have selected all of the objects and selected export as Collada. When I then import the file back into Sweet Home 3D it only has one object. I'm obviously doing this process wrong.

[image: Sweet Home 3D]

[image: 4 Turnstiles]

[image: 3 Turnstiles]

[image: Original Import into Sweet Home 3D]

[image: New Import into Sweet Home 3D]

Comment: The easiest solution I would suspect is that in the export dialogue box you have _Selection Only_ enabled. If you can't see that on the right side of the box, hit _N_ to bring up the side bar menu.

Comment: The  'Selection Only' enabled is not ticked?